# Fast loading multiple .npy files into data generator

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I do have thousands of .npy files stored in my hard disk, each containing a single matrix with dimensions `[128, T]`, where T is variable (on average T=800). Each .npy file has size around 2Mb, depending on the matrix shape.

These matrices are then passed to a generator, which yields batches of 32 to a neural network. The Python code used to pass the matrices into the generator is:

```
def load_batch(path_list):
    np_list = []
        
    for path in path_list:
        np_list.append(np.load(path))
           
    return np_list
```

which, given a list of paths of the .npy files, returns a list of the corresponding NumPy matrices.

This code takes, on average, 0.6s to return a list of 32 matrices. I am using append because this is usually a quick operation.

I am aware that the speed of the hard disk buffer does have an influence on timings but, right now, I really would like to shrink the amount of time required as much as possible by just modifying the code in a smart way.

As an alternative, I tried implementing multi-processing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def reader(filename):
    return np.load(filename)

def load_multiprocess(path_list, n_cores=5):
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    np_list = pool.map(reader, path_list)

    return np_list
```

However, the performance is much worse. I had a look around stackoverflow, and I got the idea that my specific application could not benefit from multiprocessing.

To summarize, I am looking for any kind of advice for one of these two tasks:

1. Improving the speed of the first code (even 0.1s less would mean a lot).
2. Using multiprocessing in the right way, if possible.

SOLUTION AND BENCHMARK

Out of the three methods here proposed, user7138814's solution seems to generally improve a lot the execution speed. However, things seem to change when the data is loaded while training a neural network: even though mapping is by itself still the quicker method for loading data, the overall training time seems to increase, I have no idea where and why, as timings using the mapping load are always better.

Below, I will do a benchmark of the three methods.First, define the methods:

```
import numpy as np

# my initial method
def load_batch(path_list):
    np_list = []
        
    for path in path_list:
        np_list.append(np.load(path))
           
    return np_list
    
# Aaj Kaal's method
def load_batch1(path_list):
    return [np.load(path) for path in path_list]
    
# user7138814's method    
def load_batch2(path_list):
    np_list = []
        
    for path in path_list:
        np_list.append(np.load(path, mmap_mode='r'))
    return np_list
```

I defined a list of paths as follows:

```
batches_list = []
batch_size = 32
for n in range(0,150):
    batches_list.append(X_path_list[n*batch_size:n*batch_size+batch_size])
```

The list contains 150 batches of 32 paths each, it should be enough to calculate the mean.

Then, each method is executed using passing to it exactly the same data.

```
import time

# my initial method
timing0 = []
for l in batches_list:
    start = time.time()
    load_batch(l)
    end = time.time()
    timing0.append(end-start)
print(np.mean(timing0))

# Aaj Kaal's method
timing1 = []
for l in batches_list:
    start = time.time()
    load_batch1(l)
    end = time.time()
    timing1.append(end-start)
print(np.mean(timing1))

# user7138814's method 
timing2 = []
for l in batches_list:
    start = time.time()
    load_batch2(l)
    end = time.time()
    timing2.append(end-start)
    print(np.mean(timing2))
```

Output (mean timing in seconds over 150 executions):

> 0.022530150413513184

> 0.022546884218851725

> 0.009580903053283692

Results seem to be consistent when changing length of `batches_list` and `batch_size`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe memory mapping the files will be beneficial due to lazy loading. If you would use for example

```
np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r')
```

the creation of the numpy array becomes almost a no-op, but later in the pipeline you pay the price. This could provide a speedup if it results in processing the data in parallel with reading from disk.

Comment: This seems to be the better way, I will add a benchmark in my initial question, thanks.

Comment: I confirm that this is the faster method, out of the three investigated, to load data and feed them into a neural network. However, this seems to overall slow down the training process of the network.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using use list comprehension. Replace

```
def load_batch(path_list):
    np_list = []
        
    for path in path_list:
        np_list.append(np.load(path))
           
    return np_list
```

with

```
def load_batch(path_list):
    return [np.load(path) for path in path_list]
```

In fact you can get rid of the function and directly use list comprehension. If functional call is required use lambda